# Breaking gut strings even if the instrument is 'parked'

Tags: strings, harp

One of my lever harps got natural gut strings which I am currently not playing (carpal tunnel syndrome, sigh), it's *parked* in the living room. However, sometimes any gut string will just break at any moment, perhaps once a month usually in the upper 2 octaves (1st and 2nd octave).

The tension is pretty hard but not as hard as a pedal harp. I heard about the breaking point of strings, and that the harp tension is usually around 50%-60% of the breaking point.

Another fact is air humidity by around 40%, pretty constant. Temperature between 19-23 Celsius (66-74 Fahrenheit).

So the question is, why do they break? How can I avoid that? Should I park an instrument by lowering the tension, but what about changes of tension for soundboard and neck?

Comment: Gut strings don't have much of a lifetime in general.

Comment: i must admit i don't have the guts for strings like these. These strings make me sick to my stomach.

Comment: @NeilMeyer  shame! shame!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surfing various harp-help fora suggests that gut string life is never very long.

Here's one bit of advice from some string-selling shop,

> Gut strings are covered with a protective layer of varnish or a
>   lacquer that is slowly worn away by use. Once that protective layer
>   has gone, the string will probably not last much longer as it becomes
>   more hydroscopic (sensitive to moisture and temperature change). A
>   sure sign of this happening is when the fibres of the string starting
>   to fray and peel off. Spotting this will mean that you may be able to
>   pre-empt a string breaking and change it first

So if your strings had been used for a while, they may have been in "stage one" of death, and then time & humidity took their toll on your harp.